# How do I select multiple items in a DataGrid?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

how to multiple select the datagrid? i can't figure it out. i know this is a bit stupid question, but i don't know how to apply it. help me sir/maam. thanks

Comment: I changed the subject line b/c the question had nothing to do w/ Flash Builder 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `allowMultipleSelection="true"` property of the DataGrid to allow multiple selections.

Comment: @user637908 @Jason Towne has the correct answer.  Please quantify "it didn't work".  Did you get a compiler error? or a run time error?  Are you using the Spark DataGrid or the MX DataGrid?  How about you show some code.

Comment: You have to hold the Ctrl key down to select multiple records as well.